# Defining enantiomer of morphine by R/S designation

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

How to know if the following chemical structure of morphine is an R or S? What I basically need to know is: which chirality center do we use to make the decision?

$\hskip2in$[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure that you are showing is neither R nor S.

As it has five chirality centers you need to look at all of them.

$\hskip3in$[image]

You can see in the above figure that there are three R and two S centers in the configuration of morphine that you posted.